# Leaflet.js centerOn function issue

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have an issue with Leaflet. I'm trying to add a function which permits to pan to given coordinates. It's working but the map automatically reverts to its initial position (after a few milliseconds). I'm afraid I can't find my mistake here.

Here is the code:

```css
.btn {
  background: #3498db;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  -webkit-border-radius: 6;
  -moz-border-radius: 6;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #2b8ecc;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2b8ecc, #4d687a);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2b8ecc, #4d687a);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2b8ecc, #4d687a);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2b8ecc, #4d687a);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2b8ecc, #4d687a);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 10;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.latlng{
    position: fixed;
    top:20px;
    right: 12px;
    color: white;
    font-Family: Arial;   
    font-size: 14px;
}

.latlng input[type="submit"]{
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="overflow-y: hidden; background: #666666;">
    <head>
        <title>WIMP</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <meta name="description" content="Geo Tactical System">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-M2wvCLH6DSRazYeZRIm1JnYyh22purTM+FDB5CsyxtQJYeKq83arPe5wgbNmcFXGqiSH2XR8dT/fJISVA1r/zQ==" crossorigin=""/>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-lInM/apFSqyy1o6s89K4iQUKg6ppXEgsVxT35HbzUupEVRh2Eu9Wdl4tHj7dZO0s1uvplcYGmt3498TtHq+log==" crossorigin=""></script>
    </head>
    <div id="mapid" style="position: fixed; width: 98.5vw; height: 90vh; bottom: 12px;"></div>
    <script>
        var mymap = L.map('mapid', { zoomControl:false }).setView([48.866, 2.3333], 13);

        L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
            maxZoom: 18,
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                    '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                    'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
            id: 'mapbox.streets'
        }).addTo(mymap);      
    </script>
    <body>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#"></a>
                <a href="#"></a>
                <a href="#"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form class="latlng" onsubmit="centerOn(document.getElementById('lat').value, document.getElementById('lng').value);">
            Lattitude:
            <input type="text" name="lat" id="lat" />
            Longitude:
            <input type="text" name="lng" id="lng" />
            <input type="submit" value="Centrer" />
        </form>       
        <script>
            function centerOn(lat, lng){
                //mymap.setView({lat:lat, lng:lng}, mymap.getZoom());
                mymap.panTo([lat, lng]);
                //alert("Lattitude: " + lat + " longitude: " + lng);
            }
            
            function onMapHover(e){
                document.getElementById("lat").value = e.latlng.lat;
                document.getElementById("lng").value = e.latlng.lng;   
            }
            mymap.on("mousemove", onMapHover);
        </script>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop `postback` to prevent it from resetting. Each time you click on `center`, your page is posted back to server which loads the page again.

You can fix this by doing following steps:

modify

```
onsubmit="centerOn(
```

to

```
onsubmit="return centerOn(
```

and change

```
function centerOn(lat, lng){
  //mymap.setView({lat:lat, lng:lng}, mymap.getZoom());
  mymap.panTo([lat, lng]);
  //alert("Lattitude: " + lat + " longitude: " + lng);
}
```

to

```
function centerOn(lat, lng){
  //mymap.setView({lat:lat, lng:lng}, mymap.getZoom());
  mymap.panTo([lat, lng]);
  return false;
  //alert("Lattitude: " + lat + " longitude: " + lng);
}
```

See working sample below

```css
.btn {
  background: #3498db;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  -webkit-border-radius: 6;
  -moz-border-radius: 6;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #2b8ecc;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2b8ecc, #4d687a);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2b8ecc, #4d687a);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2b8ecc, #4d687a);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2b8ecc, #4d687a);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2b8ecc, #4d687a);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 10;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.latlng{
    position: fixed;
    top:20px;
    right: 12px;
    color: white;
    font-Family: Arial;   
    font-size: 14px;
}

.latlng input[type="submit"]{
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="overflow-y: hidden; background: #666666;">
    <head>
        <title>WIMP</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <meta name="description" content="Geo Tactical System">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-M2wvCLH6DSRazYeZRIm1JnYyh22purTM+FDB5CsyxtQJYeKq83arPe5wgbNmcFXGqiSH2XR8dT/fJISVA1r/zQ==" crossorigin=""/>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-lInM/apFSqyy1o6s89K4iQUKg6ppXEgsVxT35HbzUupEVRh2Eu9Wdl4tHj7dZO0s1uvplcYGmt3498TtHq+log==" crossorigin=""></script>
    </head>
    <div id="mapid" style="position: fixed; width: 98.5vw; height: 90vh; bottom: 12px;"></div>
    <script>
        var mymap = L.map('mapid', { zoomControl:false }).setView([48.866, 2.3333], 13);

        L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
            maxZoom: 18,
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                    '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                    'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
            id: 'mapbox.streets'
        }).addTo(mymap);      
    </script>
    <body>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#"></a>
                <a href="#"></a>
                <a href="#"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form class="latlng" onsubmit="return centerOn(document.getElementById('lat').value, document.getElementById('lng').value);">
            Lattitude:
            <input type="text" name="lat" id="lat" />
            Longitude:
            <input type="text" name="lng" id="lng" />
            <input type="submit" value="Centrer" />
        </form>       
        <script>
            function centerOn(lat, lng){
                //mymap.setView({lat:lat, lng:lng}, mymap.getZoom());
                mymap.panTo([lat, lng]);
                return false;
                //alert("Lattitude: " + lat + " longitude: " + lng);
            }
            
            function onMapHover(e){
                document.getElementById("lat").value = e.latlng.lat;
                document.getElementById("lng").value = e.latlng.lng;   
            }
            mymap.on("mousemove", onMapHover);
        </script>    
    </body>
</html>
```